# How do I refresh a Form to use the latest version of a Query?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm modifying the Query: EcoResProductListPage which is the datasource for Form: EcoResProductListPage.

I've added a join to the InventTable, and the query seems to work fine. The problem is, the form itself is using the original version of the query (without the join I added).

If I remove and re-add the datasource, this works, but I lose the datasource in each of the columns on the Grid and basically have to rebuild the form. I can do this -- but I assumed there has to be an easier way.

How do I refresh the datasource on the form to use the latest version of the query, without having to entirely rebuild the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just press enter in Query property node. 
I do not remember what happens with any code you changed on the datasource.